# MVC App using LINQ/Entity to filter data

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, linq-to-entities

I have an MVC project that uses Entity/LINQ in an attempt to pull/filter Customer data into a Customer data model. I have added a [Not Mapped] property to the data model called *IsMyCustomer*. The user is presented a list of all customers and has an option to assign any of the customers to their personal work list by clicking a button. This action ultimately sets the *IsMyCustomer* value to true for that given record.

There is also a *MyCustOnly* checkbox which when clicked is supposed to filter the list of customers to only those which the user has assigned to themselves(*IsMyCustomer* = true).

```
var db = new EDM_Customer();

//get current logged in user's ID
string curUID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

//get cust_ids assigned to logged in user
var userCustomerItems = from uCI in db.user_customer
                        where uCI.uid == curUID
                        select uCI.cust_id;

//get all customer data
var customerItems = from cI in db.align_customer
                    select cI;

List<int> myCustIds = userCustomerItems.ToList();
foreach (var cust in myCustIds)
{        
    //set IsMyCustomer = true for each assined cust_id
    customerItems.Where(c => c.cust_id == cust).ToList().ForEach(mc => mc.IsMyCustomer = true);                
}

int allCount = customerItems.Count();

//MyCustOnly checkbox checked displays only my customers. Unchecked show all customers
if (filterModel.MyCustOnly)
{
    //filter customerItems to where IsMyCustomer = true
    customerItems = from cI in customerItems
                      where cI.IsMyCustomer == true
                      select cI;
}

int myCount = customerItems.Count();
```

I have verified I am setting *IsMyCustomer* = true in the foreach block for assigned customers. Variable *allCount* shows an accurate count for all customers, however, *myCount* shows 0.

Assistance in resolving this would be appreciated.

Comment: My first thought would be to debug and check to make sure that filterModel.MyCustOnly is actually true.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do with this code. Is the line where you set all IsMyCustomer properties to true just to test the next if block or something? Because if it's not, then your final if block and what it's doing is completely pointless. Also pretty sure you could combine your first two LINQ queries with a join to achieve the same thing in the filtering you do in the first foreach loop.

Comment: There is more to this than what I showed.  The foreach block takes the  cust_id's that match the user_id's pairings read from a db and sets IsMyCustomer = true which is then used to display an either add or delete button for each record in the list. This is what users click to manage their work list. The users also have the option to check a MyCustOnly checkbox which filters the work list to show only customers assigned to them rather than all customers. Therefore, the foreach sets IsMyCustomer which is then used to know what to display should the user check the MyCustOnly checkbox.

Comment: @hashtagnatty I have verified I am setting IsMyCustomer = true in that my Add/Delete buttons are accurate depending on if a customer has been added or not.

Comment: @hashtagnatty I misread your response, Yes *MyCustOnly* is being set to true also. When it is not checked, *myCount* = all customer volume. When it is checked, *myCount* = 0.

Comment: @ASPed In response to your most previous comment:
That tells me that when `MyCustOnly` is true, then your linq statement that executes in the `if (filterModel.MyCustOnly)` block is finding no `customerItems` that have `IsMyCustomer` set to true.

Comment: @ASPed One way to verify this is to change that linq statement into a foreach loop where you populate a second `List<CustomerItems>` by checking if each element in `customerItems` has `IsMyCustomer` set to true. 
The final solution will probably be changing the `.ForEach` part of the `customerItems.Where...` statement into an actual `foreach` loop and stepping through the execution to make sure you're setting everything correctly.